# Show that there exists a unique function with a certain property

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

"Let  $~f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}~$ be a function, and let $~c~$ be a natural number.

Show that there exists  a unique function $~a: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}~$ such that $~a(0)=c~$ and $~a(n+1)=f(n,a(n)) ~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$".

To prove the theorem is it sufficient to show by induction that for every natural number $~N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a unique function $~a_N:\{n \in \mathbb{N}: n \leq N\} \to \mathbb{N}~$ such that $~a_N(0)=c~$ and $~a_N(n+1)=f(n,a_N(n)) ~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}~$ such that $~n<N$ ?

Comment: Technically, what you want to prove is not quite the same.  What's to stop the various $a_N$ from being different functions?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exists another function $b$ such that $b(0) = c$, and let $m$ be the minimum index such that $a(m) \neq b(m)$

This implies that

$$a(m) = f(m, a(m-1)) \neq b(m) = f(m, b(m-1)$$

But by hypothesis $b(m-1) = a(m-1)$, and this implies

$$f(m, a(m-1)) \neq f(m, a(m-1))$$ which is impossible since $f$ is a function.